# Rotate matrix +/- radian / degree

Tags: julia

Here is a matrix:

```
A = reshape(collect(1:81), (9, 9))
```

How may I rotate this matrix in +/- radians/degrees?

Lets say I wish to do a 45 degree rotation

[image]

I guess imagine all the 1's in the middle lining up at a 45 degree angle...

Any packages to recommend?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageTransformations.jl?

Comment: Looks like it will suit my needs thanks again